# Performance of MySQL Cluster vs MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-cluster

I am working on a project for which the database is the major bottleneck. For a myriad of reasons, further optimization of the on a programming level is something we want to avoid as much as possible. We would like a solution to potentially increase the speed of our site. We are currently using MySQL, and I have read that MySQL Cluster stores the entire database in memory.

Right now, we have one database server. I am considering running two equally powerful servers with MySQL cluster with enough total memory to store the entire database in memory. With that being said, have you guys noticed a considerable speed increase going from MySQL to MySQL cluster? More specifically, does the in-memory storage of the database actually speed up the database substantially? Also, what is the role of indexes if the tables are already stored in memory? Our queries involve a lot of subqueries and joins if that makes a difference. I understand that running a benchmark is the only way to truly know, but I want to gain some background information before delving into this project.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-compared.html

Comment: MySQL cluster will likely require a few changes to your table structure as it's not absolutely 1:1 with innodb, which may require some code changes. Also it doesn't exactly store the whole thing in memory. Depending on where your bottle neck is you may want to look at having some slaves (if it's read) and reading from slaves using replication as it will require fewer changes.

Comment: The other thing I'll add to my comment is mysql cluster has a complex sharding scheme that requires thought as to how you structure indexes and primary keys to influence how it splits data up. That's one of the reasons it won't always result in an immediate speed up.